# PHPUnit installation issue

Tags: macos, phpunit, mamp

it gives error when i run below command.

pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit

```
WARNING: channel "pear.phpunit.de" has updated its protocols, use "pear channel-update
pear.phpunit.de" to update
downloading PHPUnit-3.6.12.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit-3.6.12.tgz (119,220 bytes)
..........................done: 119,220 bytes
ERROR: failed to create /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/share/pear/PHPUnit/Extensions 
/PhptTestCase/.tmpLogger.php: fopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/share/pear/PHPUnit 
/Extensions/PhptTestCase/.tmpLogger.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I am using mac and mamp and i want to install PHPUnit, plz help.

---edited---

i granted some permissions, now it shows below error
Could not delete /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/phpunit, cannot rename /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/.tmpphpunit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is a problem with permissions.

1. rm -rf /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/phpunit
2. chmod 0777 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/ -r

And then reinstall phpunit.

Comment: hi, it helped me .. but it gives error when i check version or run any command of phpunit --> msmac:~ Mohdshahid$ phpunit --version
-bash: /usr/local/bin/phpunit: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/php: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Run the install as root using `sudo`.

```
sudo pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```